# How to save floats from txt file with multiple arrays?

Tags: python, list

I would like to extract data from a txt file stored as:

```
[ 0 1 2 3]
[ 4 5 6 7]
[ 8 9 10 11]
```

(there is no vertical space between the brackets though)

Would you have any idea how to proceed? I have tried this below which does not recognize the brackets.

```
with open(filename) as f:
    array = []
    for line in f:
        array.append([float(x) for x in line.split()])
```

Comment: in which form you want to display your output

Comment: put here whiich txt file you calling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try the following:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    array = []
    for line in f: 
        array.append([float(x) for x in line.replace('[', '').replace(']', '').strip().split()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming each sublist in brackets is stored on a new line.

Replace `line.split()` with:

```
line.strip()[1:-1].split()
```

This simply gets rid of both brackets (or both the first and the last character) with `[1:-1]`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add check if the string is digit or not to achieve this just add `if x.isdigit()`, see below example:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    array = []
    for line in f:
        array.append([float(x) for x in line.split() if x.isdigit()])
print array
```

> output : [[0.0, 1.0, 2.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0], [8.0, 9.0, 10.0]]

Answer (score 0):

The following code evaluates the contents of the file line-per-line as python code. However, even though this works, this is probably not the optimal solution, especially since it could potentially dangerous and should only be done, if you can be sure there will not be any malicious content in the file.

```
import ast

arr = []
with open('values.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f: 
        arr.extend(ast.literal_eval(line.replace("[ ", "[").replace(" ", ",")))
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have commas between these integers.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
    arr = []
    for line in f:
        integer_array = eval(line.replace(' ', ','))
        arr.append([float(item) for item in integer_array])
    print(arr)
```